# .net framework 4.5.1 missing from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

Just did a fresh rebuild of my machine.

Opening a previous project running .Net 4.5.1, it says

> "The C# project is targeting .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1, which is
>   not installed on this machine"

Installed 4.5.2, re-installed VS, re-installed IIS, .NET, and did aspnet_iisreg -i as well.

If I create a new project, 4.5.1 is not in the list of Target Frameworks.

4.5.2 is installed on the machine and shown in the add/remove programs list.

Comment: @PhilipPittle The question is how to solve my error and obviously get my solution up and running again.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Once you have Visual Studio 2012 installed (and all applicable [updates](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305)), you need to install the [4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40772). Once you have it installed, you'll have 4.5.1 available.

Installing 4.5.2 does *not* include 4.5.1 for framework targeting. If you want both 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 available as Target Frameworks, you need to install both.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I'm trying this now and will update shortly. I just assumed that 4.5.2 included 4.5.1... Silly me.

Comment: Worked like a champ! Also odd (to me at least), why visual studios shows me the error, then give me a link to download the correct installers to fix it and they don't.

Comment: For me, installing the Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5.1 wasn't enough. I had to install the 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack.